# Visual Studio GIT Revert

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I inadvertently kept some uncommitted minor changes from months ago, when I sync'd with the master branch trying to get the latest it has auto-merged the entire project back to a much older version. I want to rollback this sync operation but all the options (reset --hard, revert etc..) seem to have 0 tangible effect.

Any advice?

Comment: We don't really know the state of your branch. Do you have any changes staged? Which branch do you have checked out? Do you want to return to a previous commit? Your question leaves too many gaps for anyone to hazard an answer.

Comment: Do you want to remove these uncommitted changes or keep these uncommitted changes but remove sync changes? How about `git checkout GOODSHA -- path/to/filename`

Comment: How did you reset changes? Provide the detail steps here.

Comment: my current branch is master, no changes staged except the ones I've recently committed. Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with GIT to know what other details might be pertinent

Comment: Do you want to remain the uncommitted changes after reset? You said "but all the options (reset --hard, revert etc..) seem to have 0 tangible effect.", how did you do it? Provide the detail steps here.